# Combination Problem : $6$ Countries , $4$ players from each country

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

$6$ Countries participate a world tournament .

Each country has $4$ players.  One Cricket player , One Rugby player , one Volleyball player and one Football player.

Need to select a team of $8$ members.

**Rule :**

First four members must be selected from two countries out of 6 countries and 2 from each selected two countries.

Then we must select last four members from the rest of countries , by selecting two countries and 2 from each selected countries.

**My attempt**

Number of ways selecting two countries out of $6$ countries $$=\binom{6}{2}$$

Number of combinations for selecting two players from each selected country $$=\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}$$

Now there are four countries left.

So number of ways selecting two countries from the left $$=\binom{4}{2}$$

Number of combinations for selecting two players from each selected country $$=\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}$$

So altogether all combinations $$=\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}\cdot \binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}$$

But one of my friends told me that the his answer is $$=\binom{6}{4}\cdot \binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}$$

What is correct ? This is confusing. Need a help.

Comment: The wording strikes me as odd.  Unless two particular countries are each guaranteed to have two members on the team, we are just selecting four countries which will each have two players on the team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If just $2$ members each from $4$ countries are to be selected, your friend is correct, **but**
the rules are very specific, and imply that there is a hierarchy in the choices
(reason not specified).

A plausible assumption could be that we are to have two labelled groups, $A$ and $B$,
**and your computation is correct according to the rules.**

Your friend chooses all $4$ participating countries at one go,
*but they would need to divide these $4$ into two labelled groups* in $\binom42$ ways